# scanf " %c" does not read whitespace in C

Tags: c, char, scanf

I need to read user input characters including whitespace and store them in linked list. If i use scanf("%c", &charas) it runs loop 2 times and allows to input only 1 time. If i use scanf(" %c", &charas) it does not read whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct sarasas {
    char zenklas;
    struct sarasas *kitas;
};
typedef struct sarasas Sarasas;
typedef Sarasas *SarasasPtr;

int tarpas(struct sarasas* sar, int index)
{
    struct sarasas* dabartinis = sar;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=index; i++)
    {
        if (dabartinis->zenklas == 32)
            return(i);
        dabartinis=dabartinis->kitas;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, n, tarpo_vieta;
    char charas;
    SarasasPtr sar;
    sar=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof(Sarasas));
    SarasasPtr pradzia=sar;
    printf("Iveskite skaiciu n\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Veskite elementus: \n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        scanf("%c\n", &charas);
            sar->zenklas=charas;
            sar->kitas=(SarasasPtr) malloc(sizeof(Sarasas));
            sar=sar->kitas;

    }
    sar->kitas=NULL;
    //tarpo_vieta=tarpas(pradzia, n);
    printf("%d\n", tarpo_vieta);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", pradzia->zenklas);
        pradzia=pradzia->kitas;
    }
}
```

Also i cannot use arrays.

Comment: When you using functions from scanf family, always check for the return value to prevent weird behaviors. I'm not sure if this will fix, but I'd try that first.

Answer (score 2):

use [**fgets**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)

```
fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
```

Or

use

```
scanf("%[^\n]",word);
```

Comment: I tried both methods, loop just goes through, it doesn't allow me to input anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getchar()` to read one character instead of `scanf()`:

```
 charas = getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one, some time our scanf and and also gets will not work properly, these happen so to read the value using different read function,

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",word);
```

this scanf will read your value upto new line means till you will not key enter this will read your input(size of string is a limit).

```
scanf("%[^*]",word);
```

this will read up to your '*' char if you pressed.

Answer (score 0):

First try running this:

```
char c;
do {
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
} while (c != '.');
```

While the code apparently deals with a single character per loop, what the program actually does it it takes input of any length from the user and then prints it character by character until it encounters a period.

You can use a similar loop, just instead of `putchar` in my code, write the code to add c to the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with `scanf("%d", &n);` as although is does read in `int n`, it leaves the `'\n'` or <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `stdin`.  This is scanned in with the next `scanf("%c\n", &charas);`.

Also a problem: `scanf("%c\n", &charas);` which does not return until a `char`, optional white-space (like `\n`, all which is consumed) *and* a non-white-space is entered.  (That non-white-space is returned to `stdin` though)

As @miushock says, check scanf() family results.

Rather than:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
  scanf("%c\n", &charas);
  sar->zenklas=charas;
}
```

Do

```
char buf[40];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &n) != 1) Handle_InputError();
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
  if (strlen(buf) != 2) Handle_InputError();
  sar->zenklas = buf[0];
}
```